# View Pager and Gridview wrap_content

Tags: java, android

I have custom view with extends LinearLayout. Custom view is viewpager with grid view inside. I add "wrap_content" wherever possible, but my view spend whole screen or only one grid's view line.
I find examples GridView with wrap_content function, but it is not help me

[image]